# Is there a Markdown viewer in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, markdown

I've added a `README.md` to my project and am using it actively as I go along writing my app. I'd like to finalize it before pushing to GitHub but I don't see a way to preview the markdown in Android Studio.

I saw something about a plug-in possibly being available, but it looked a bit janky. Is there something being used commonly use out there?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Ok, so with my version of Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 2, the Jetbrains Markdown plugin is pre-packaged and automatically installed. BUT, the preview panel doesn't work in the Android Studio version of Jetbrains out of the box. There's already a [great write-up on this here](https://joachimschuster.de/posts/android-studio-fix-markdown-plugin-again/). Here's the summary:

- Check for the `Markdown` plugin at `File` | `Settings` | `Plugins`
- If that's installed, follow the instructions in the link above to change the Java Runtime for the IDE to one with JCEF (Java Chromium Embedded Framework) support: `Shift` + `Ctrl` + `A` to open search. Search for "Choose Boot Java Runtime for the IDE…", execute it, select a runtime with JCEF in its title (like the default), and hit `Ok` to install it.
- After reboot, opening a *.md file will show a preview pane!

[image]

Comment: It can't be JVM versions: I have IntelliJ IDEA powered with embedded Jetbrains OpenJDK 11.0.14, and Android Studio 2021 with embedded 11.0.13. Studio doesn't show preview; IDEA does.
Android Studio:
```
Runtime version: 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
```

IntelliJ:
```
Runtime version: 11.0.14.1+1-b1751.46 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
```

Comment: However, I was able to update Android Studio to use 11.0.14 from IntelliJ IDEA installation, it was automatically shown in the "Choose Boot Java Runtime for the IDE…" menu, and even few variants, including one with JCEF

Comment: This worked for me when using Android Studio Flamingo, the only difference being that I chose JBRSDK 17 with JCEF.

Comment: This worked for me on Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 and selecting `JBRSDK 11.0.16.8-2043.64-jcef`

Comment: Changing Java runtime may make your IDE not work correctly.  I've faced this before.